# Entity FrameWork Error when adding migration to MVC dotnotcore 2.0 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm relatively new to dot net core and EF core. In Package Manager Console, when I type 'EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration Initial' I get the following error.

```
PM> EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration Initial
Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6.x commands are installed. The Entity Framework Core version is executing. You can fully qualify the command to select which one to execute, 'EntityFramework\Add-Migration' for EF6.x and 'EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration' for EF Core.
EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration : Exception calling "CreateInstanceAndUnwrap" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file 
specified."
At line:1 char:1
+ EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration Initial
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException,Add-Migration
```

I've googled the error but have yet to find any working solutions. Any ideas? My machine is 64 bit running Windows 10. I am using VS 2017 professional 15.5.2

Many thanks

Comment: Is the right startup and target project correct? The startup should be the one with the connection strings and the target one the one with the context class. Basically the EF package is not found which means is not installed in the right project or the wrong project is being targeted.

Comment: Sorry im not following. What exactly should I be checking for? My connection string is in a file i created called appsettings.json. This default connection is then referenced in my Startup.cs

Comment: How many projects do you have in the solution? Did you install EF through Nuget?

Comment: Just one project in my solution. I did install through Nuget but the tutorial I am following also had Package Reference includes in the .csproj file. So i also have certain references in here such as :    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.0.0-preview2-final" />

Comment: you don't add the references if installed through Nuget. Remove any references, uninstall and install it again.

Comment: Did that but now I get:  Could not load assembly '<projectname>'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project '<projectname>'.